# Why mongodb oplog is always empty?

Tags: java, mongodb, lucene

I'm trying to write synchronizer between MongoDB and Lucene. Idea is to implement application that will tail oplog and reproduce everything in Lucene. As a basis I'm using [this](http://jaihirsch.github.io/straw-in-a-haystack/mongodb/2014/08/18/mongo-oplog-tailing/) post

The problem is that my oplog is always empty:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find({},{"ts":1}).sort({$natural: -1}).hasNext()
false

rs0:PRIMARY> db.Message.find({}).count()
729

rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find({}).hasNext()
false

rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find()
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `db.oplog.rs.find()` yields nothing?

Comment: @GergelyBacso yes, I updated question with the output

Comment: Do you have replica enabled?

Comment: @GergelyBacso yes it is enabled. And it worked, because I test it using mongo-connector

Comment: Do 'use local' to use the local database then do 'db.oplog.rs.find()'.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I tested it, and now it showing all messages. Thanks a lot! Could you please create an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All replica set members contain a copy of the oplog, in the [local.oplog.rs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/local-database/#local.oplog.rs) collection. In order to query the oplog you have to use the [local database](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/local-database/#the-local-database).

```
use local;
db.oplog.rs.find();
```